# What is "Laundry"-memory on Juniper MX systems?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-mx

When displaying the current memory usage on Juniper MX systems (running JunOS 21.4, in case it should matter), I do see an entry for `Laundry`. For example:

```
> show system processes extensive
Mem: 13330M Active, 430M Inact, 13918M Laundry, 3198M Wired, 1374M Buf, 904M Free
(...)
```

Other Juniper systems like the EX and QFX switches do not show this field under `show system processes extensive`. Junipers [own documentation for memory management](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/verification/routing-engine-memory-usage.html) also does not mention `Laundry` anywhere, although it explains all the other fields in detail.

**What is this "Laundry"-memory, and is it safe to assume it can be released by the system if required for something else? (Or is the above system close to running out of memory?)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junos OS is based on FreeBSD:

> ### Laundry
>
> - Queue for managing dirty inactive pages, which must be cleaned ("laundered") before they can be reused
> - Managed by a separate thread, the laundry thread, instead of the page daemon
> - Laundry thread launders a small number of pages to balance the inactive and laundry queues
> - Frequency of laundering depends on:
>
>   - How many clean pages the page daemon is freeing; more frees contributes to a higher frequency of laundering
>   - The size of the laundry queue relative to the inactive queue; if the laundry queue is growing, we will launder more frequently
> - Pages are scanned by the laundry thread (starting from the head of the queue):
>   Pages which have been referenced are moved back to the active queue or the tail of the laundry queue
>   Dirty pages are laundered and then moved close to the head of the inactive queue

https://wiki.freebsd.org/Memory